# cannot find module “@angular/core/src/metadata/directives”

Tags: angularjs, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am getting this error when trying to view my Ionic2 application. I have tried to implement a weather application within my application. I am unsure if this is causing an error.

I am unsure where the error is coming from so I am unsure which code to post, so, please let me know if there is a certain part of code you need to see.

cannot find module “@angular/core/src/metadata/directives”

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import { firebaseConfig } from './credentials';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { Unsubscribe } from '@firebase/util';
import {MenuPage} from '../pages/menu/menu';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  rootPage: any;

  constructor(
    platform: Platform,
    statusBar: StatusBar,
    splashScreen: SplashScreen
  ) {
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

    const unsubscribe: Unsubscribe = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      if (user) {
        this.rootPage = HomePage;
        unsubscribe();
      } else {
        this.rootPage = 'LoginPage';
        unsubscribe();
      }
    });

    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      statusBar.styleDefault();
      splashScreen.hide();
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: post your code in the question

Comment: As i mentioned I dont know where the error is coming from so I am unsure which part of the code to post, Sorry

Comment: @ukbount post your component.ts

Comment: hmm is there any place you are using @angular/core/src/metadata/directives” in code?

Comment: I have added it too the question

Comment: I tried looking but not that i can see, do you think it is a file trying to use it?

Comment: yes i think so since deep imports are not supported

Comment: I've searched, do you know what file maybe calling it?

Comment: import {Input} from '@angular/core/src/metadata/directives'; that is in the app.module,ts

Answer (score 14):

**[`Deep imports`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/docs/PUBLIC_API.md)** are not supported as i mentioned in the comment above, Change

**From**

```
import {Input} from '@angular/core/src/metadata/directives';
```

**To**

```
 import {Input} from '@angular/core';
```

Comment: it is still showing the same error, It may be used in another folder

Comment: just double check and do a restart

Comment: a restart of the application?

Comment: npm cache clean and then npm start

Comment: its still showing i'm still unsure. Thanks for the help

Comment: This code is in the main.js file, It is throwing an error                            
  "use strict";
/* harmony export (binding) */ __webpack_require__.d(__webpack_exports__, "a", function() { return PlacesComponent; });
/* harmony import */ var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__angular_core__ = __webpack_require__(1);
throw new Error("Cannot find module \"@angular/core/src/metadata/directives\"");

Comment: Users of Visual Studio Code beware as the software may randomly change `@angular/core` to the path `@angular/core/src/metadata/directives` if you add/remove an import.

Answer (score 0):

Change the import to:

```
import {Input} from '@angular/core';
```

And the Restart the Application.